# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' on UILocalNotifcation Load

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

When loading my application from a local notification I am trying to read its payload. To do so I have the following code:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Loading Stuff

    UILocalNotification *localNotif =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        [(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController setSelectedIndex:1];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
        IMTRewardsViewController *rvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rewardsView"];
        [rvc loadPushNotification:localNotif];
        [nav pushViewController:rvc animated:NO];

    }

    return YES;
}
```

IMTRewardsController.h:

```
-(NSDictionary *)loadPushNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;
```

IMTRewardsController.m:

```
- (NSDictionary *)loadPushNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"%@",notification.userInfo);
    return notification.userInfo;
}
```

When I load my application from a local notification I receive the following error:

```
<Error>: -[UIViewController loadPushNotification]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e70b30
<Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController loadPushNotification]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e70b30'
```

Any idea as to how to fix this issue and keep it from cropping up in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There error indicates the view controller you've pulled back is only a UIViewController, and not a IMTRewardsViewController like you're expecting. Are you sure you set the custom class property to that type in the storyboard?

Comment: Son of a _____________! That is exactly what the problem was. Thank you sir.

Comment: No problem. This happens to me almost every single time.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to cast it first. The storyboard returns an UIViewController

```
IMTRewardsViewController *rvc = (IMTRewardsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rewardsView"];
```